# PerformanceCounterCategory to string value

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am trying to retrieve the value of my readyboost cache I wrote the following code but it says the value does not exist

```
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory pc;
            pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("ReadyBoost Cache");
            pc.GetCounters("Bytes cached");
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pc));
```

Spelling is correct, I can see the object following this code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fh4x1xb(v=vs.71).aspx

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

the parameter of GetCounters should be the instance name of the performance Counter. change your code as follows:

```
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory pc;
    pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("ReadyBoost Cache");
    foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in pc.GetCounters())
    {
        if (counter.CounterName == "Bytes cached")
        {
            //to do
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error says it cannot find the category, I know the cat is there because when I run the Microsoft version it works

Comment: What if you change System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("ReadyBoost Cache"); into as follows:

Comment: foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory cat in PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories())
            {
                if (cat.CategoryName == "ReadyBoost Cache")
                {
 
                }
            }